# How do I properly integrate flask-wtforms with AJAX for dynamic adding fields?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, wtforms

I am a beginner in ajax programming, so please bear with me.

What I want to do is to allow a user to add a form field upon a button click like so:

[Before button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVpeC.png)

[After button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vo1l.png)

For the main form, I have the following code.

```
class EnrollForm(FlaskForm):
  known_for = StringField('Known for',
    validators=[
      Length(max=LONG_STRING)
    ]
  )

  soc_med_info = FieldList(FormField(SocialMediaForm), min_entries=1)
```

Here is its subform/formfield

```
class SocialMediaForm(Form):
  social_media = SelectField('Where can we find you?', coerce=str)

  other = StringField(validators=[
    Length(max=MEDIUM_STRING)
  ])

  handle = StringField('Handle',
    validators=[
      Length(max=SHORT_STRING)
    ]
  )

  followers = StringField('Followers',
    validators=[
      Length(max=SHORT_STRING),
      Regexp('^\d*[kmKM]$', message='Input number of followers')
    ]
  )
```

The html (enroll.html)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <form method="POST"
        action="{{url_for('user.enroll')}}"
        id="enroll-form">
          {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
              <legend>
                  Be one of us
              </legend>
              <div class="form-group">
              {{ form.known_for.label(class="form-control-label") }}

              {% if form.known_for.errors %}
                {{ form.known_for(class="form-control form-control-sm is-invalid")}}
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  {% for error in form.known_for.errors %}
                      <span>{{ error }}</span>
                  {% endfor %}
                </div>
              {% else %}
                {{ form.known_for(class="form-control form-control-sm")}}
              {%endif%}
            </div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>
                    Social Media Information
                </legend>
                <span id="platforms">
                  {% include 'pages/user/platforms.html' %}
                </span>
            </fieldset>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice the included html file ("platforms.html") - this is where I render the subform field rows

```
{% for soc_med in form.soc_med_info %}
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ soc_med.social_media.label(class="form-control-label") }}

            {% if soc_med.social_media.errors %}
              {{ soc_med.social_media(class="form-control form-control-sm is-invalid")}}
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                {% for error in form.social_media.errors %}
                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>
            {% else %}
              {{ soc_med.social_media(class="form-control form-control-sm")}}
            {%endif%}
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ soc_med.handle.label(class="form-control-label") }}

            {% if soc_med.handle.errors %}
              {{ soc_med.handle(class="form-control form-control-sm is-invalid")}}
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                {% for error in form.handle.errors %}
                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>
            {% else %}
              {{ soc_med.handle(class="form-control form-control-sm")}}
            {%endif%}
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ soc_med.followers.label(class="form-control-label") }}

            {% if soc_med.followers.errors %}
              {{ soc_med.followers(class="form-control form-control-sm is-invalid")}}
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                {% for error in form.followers.errors %}
                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>
            {% else %}
              {{ soc_med.followers(class="form-control form-control-sm")}}
            {%endif%}
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            {% if loop.index == 1 %}
              <button type="button"
              id="add-soc-med-btn">
                  Add Item
              </button>
            {% else %}
              <button type="button">
                  X
              </button>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The AJAX script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#add-soc-med-btn").on("click", function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          url: "{{url_for('user.add_soc_med')}}",
          type: "POST",
          data: $("#enroll-form").serialize(),
          success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            $('#platforms').html(data)
          },
          error: function(xhr, resp, text){
            console.log(xhr, resp, text)
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The 'views':

```
@user.route('/enroll', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def enroll():
  form = EnrollForm()

  # Initialize form
  for soc_form in form.soc_med_info:
    soc_form.social_media.choices = soc_med_platforms

  if form.validate_on_submit():
    return doEnroll(request, form)

  return render_template('pages/user/enroll.html', form=form)

def doEnroll(request, form):
  pass

@user.route('/enroll/add/social_media', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def add_soc_med():
  form = EnrollForm(request.form)
  form.soc_med_info.append_entry()
  for soc_form in form.soc_med_info:
    soc_form.social_media.choices = soc_med_platforms

  return render_template('pages/user/platforms.html', form=form)
```

The 'remove row' functionality is not yet implemented.
The expected result is that field rows are added continuously, however, only one field row is added even after repeated button click.

I am assuming that this is because in the views code, "add_soc_med()"; I am re-initializing the EnrollForm. What I want to do is retain the form from the "enroll()" function and access the soc_med_info fieldlist and append an entry.

I just don't know exactly what to do.

I am using Jelle van der Zwaag's answer on this thread:
[Append entry to FieldList with Flask-WTForms using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49066046/append-entry-to-fieldlist-with-flask-wtforms-using-ajax)

Comment: Hi, one mistake which i am seeing in your ajax code is this `$('#platforms').html(data)` line so this will replace any previous content and override new one . I think you need do `$('#platforms').append(data)` this will append new form group and keep previous one as well .

Answer (score 1):

Basically your approach works.
However, after clicking on the button, you replace the entire form including the button for adding a subform. This also means that the listener for the click event is no longer allocated. To add more entries it is necessary to register the listener again after the template has been populated.
A possible solution would be the following.

```js
function handleClick(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{url_for('user.add_soc_med')}}",
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#enroll-form").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $("#add-soc-med-btn", $('#platforms').html(data))
                    .on("click", handleClick);
            },
            error: function(xhr, resp, text){
                console.log(xhr, resp, text)
            }
        });
}

$("#add-soc-med-btn").on("click", handleClick);
```