# Need SQLAlchemy WTForms Flask append children to parent form example

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms

While there is documentation for WTForms at https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ and there is also documentation for WTForms-Alchemy  at https://wtforms-alchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ the documentation really could be improved by including some examples as they would be implemented with Flask.  One challenge I am facing is creating a simple form that allows a user to update a parent and the children of a parent object.  Two other StackOverflow posts tackle this challenge.  The first (which is my own and is located at  [When using wtforms and sqlalchemy a form with a parent-child relationship appends new children to the db rather than updating existing children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033069/when-using-wtforms-and-sqlalchemy-a-form-with-a-parent-child-relationship-append) ) is complete, but contains what I suspect is a kludge.  The second is good but doesn't show how to save the form in flask:  [Append entry to FieldList with Flask-WTForms using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49066046/append-entry-to-fieldlist-with-flask-wtforms-using-ajax).  Is anybody aware of a complete and correct working flask-sqlalchemy-wtforms example of a form that updates a parent object and its children? The form should allow the user to add additional children and edit them, not simply associate the parent with existing children.

Comment: This is a screencast of how the form should behave: https://www.screencast.com/t/ODFtsqop

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with a solution that doesn't feel kludgy.  The full repo (which is still very spare) is here:  https://github.com/lfernandez55/3200_wtf_parent_child_example. Below is the update_registration view which details how the form info is persisted on an update:

```
@app.route('/update_registration', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update_registration():
    parentObj = Parent.query.filter(Parent.id == 1).first()
    form = ParentForm(id=parentObj.id, name=parentObj.name, children=parentObj.children)

    if form.add_child.data:
        form.children.append_entry()
        return render_template('update_registration.html', form=form)
    if form.remove_child.data:
        popped_entry = form.children.pop_entry()
        child = Child.query.filter(Child.id == popped_entry.data['id']).first()
        db.session.delete(child)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template('update_registration.html', form=form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        for child in form.children.data:
            if child['id'] != "":
                childObj = Child.query.filter(Child.id == child['id']).first()
                childObj.name=child['name']
                childObj.age=child['age']
            else:
                childObj = Child(name=child['name'],age=child['age'])
            parentObj.children.append(childObj)
        db.session.add(parentObj)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Parent [and children] Updated!!')
        return redirect(url_for('home_page'))
    return render_template('update_registration.html', form=form)
```